# Report Builder 3.0 - Adding textboxes together

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm currently creating a report in Report Builder 3.0. I have two textboxes containing SUMs. I want to add the values of these two textboxes together in a third textbox. How is this doable?

I need to add that I'm not working in tables or tablix.

Comment: Hmm? I don't see the problem? Can't you just make an expression in the third textbox to add the two SUMs? Perhaps if you tell us what you've tried so far and why it didn't work it may be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the SUMs:

```
=SUM(Fields!FirstField.Value, "DatasetOne") + SUM(Fields!SecondField.Value, "DatasetTwo")
```